# How can there be isolated points in an open set (in the definition of meromorphic)?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

The definition of a function $f: O \to \Bbb{C}$ from a an open subset $O$ of $\Bbb{C}$ is meromorphic if it is holomorphic (complex differentiable) on all of $O$ except for a set of isolated points.  How can you have isolated points here?  Since any neighborhood around the points that you take will have a point of $O$ in it.

Comment: Isolated from one another, not from the rest of $O$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The neighbourhood will have other points of $O$ in it, but not other points of **the set**.  For example, $f(z) = 1/z + 1/(z-1)$ is meromorphic in $O = \mathbb C$.  The set of isolated points is $\{0,1\}$ in this case.